# PHP Logical OR Operator in an IF ELSE Statement

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, boolean, logic

I have a user level login system and I want all the login users to go to the home page. I wonder why the following logic not working. Please suggest better ways.

```
$role = $_SESSION['sess_userlevel'];

if( $role == 1 || $role == 2 || $role == 3 ){
        $securep = '../';
        header('Location: '.$securep);
 }else{
  //back to the login page.
}
```

The problem with this code is that it redirects back to the login page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: It redirects back to the login page if I log in with $role == 2.

Comment: Instead of `../` you really should use the full path (e.g. `/full/path/to/page`).

Comment: Maybe you should `exit;` after the header redirect, otherwise code will continue to execute after the header statement

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to insert

```
session_start();
```

before you access the `$_SESSION` array?

Also check the result of

```
var_dump($role)
```

before your if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
$role = $_SESSION['sess_userlevel'];

if( $role == 1 || $role == 2 || $role == 3 ){
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']";
          header('location:'.$actual_link.'yourpathfile.php');
 }else{
  //back to the login page.
}
```